# Django form validation: making "required" conditional?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm new to Django (and Python), and am trying to figure out how to conditionalize certain aspects of form validation. In this case, there's a HTML interface to the application where the user can choose a date and a time from widgets. The `clean` method on the form object takes the values of the time and date fields and turns them back into a `datetime`.

In addition to the HTML interface, there's also an iPhone client making calls into the application, and I'd like to pass a UNIX timestamp-style time value in.

My form code looks like this:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_date             = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=DATE_CHOICES))
    foo_time             = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=SelectTimeWidget())
    foo_timestamp        = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

How do I make `foo_date` and `foo_time` required **unless** `foo_timestamp` is provided?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is done with the `clean` method on the form. You need to set `foo_date` and `foo_time` to `required=False`, though, because `clean` is only called after every field has been validated (see also the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).

```
class FooForm(forms.Form)
    # your field definitions

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('foo_timestamp', None) or (data.get('foo_date', None) and data.get('foo_time', None)):
            return data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Provide either a date and time or a timestamp')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking `clean` was probably the place to do this. Is it possible, though, to have the validation error against the `foo_date` and `foo_time` fields, versus a general form validation error?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: That's explained in the second example in the docs I linked to

Answer (score 10):

I found myself needing a "standard" way to do this, as my forms have several conditionally required fields. So I created a superclass with the following method:

```
def validate_required_field(self, cleaned_data, field_name, message="This field is required"):
    if(field_name in cleaned_data and cleaned_data[field_name] is None):
        self._errors[field_name] = self.error_class([message])
        del cleaned_data[field_name]
```

And then in my form's clean method I have:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(FormClass, self).clean()
    if(condition):
        self.validate_required_field(cleaned_data, 'field_name')
```

It's worked perfectly for me so far.