# Conditional Field/Form Validation using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a conditional field using django. "Approved" is a checkbox and "Date_of_approval" is a date field. "Member" is the class in-which the "clean" method is defined.

I want the date field to become a mandatory field once the approved field is checked.
The error I get using the below code is **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'**

Please also help me confirm where this code should be placed. I have it in my models page. Whenever I put it into my forms page it doesn't recognize the fields.

```
approved = models.BooleanField()
date_of_approval = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)   

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(Member, self).clean()
    approved = cleaned_data.get("approved")
    date_of_approval = cleaned_data.get("date_of_approval ")

    if approved and date_of_approval :

        if approved and not date_of_approval :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invaid input")
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Not 100% certain this is a duplicate, but it seems relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306800/django-form-validation-making-required-conditional?rq=1.

Comment: as @Peter said, this validation should be in forms..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cleaned_data` is used in form validation, not model validation. To get the cleaned field value during model validation, just reference `self`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
```

...

```
class Member(models.Model):

    # field definitions as above

    def clean(self):
        if self.approved and not self.date_of_approval:
            raise ValidationError("Approved members must have a date of approval")
```

Or fix your form so that it finds the fields in question, but there's not enough information in your question to tell why you're having problems there.

Comment: Thanks @peter for your answer. The truth is I don't even know why my form is having problems recognizing the fields. Do you know of any reason why forms will not be recognizing fields?

Comment: Its worked now. I had to include the code in another class as it didn't wouldn't work whenever I put it in a class of its own.

Comment: On the one hand, it's not magic - if your form wasn't working, there was something wrong with how you've declared it. On the other hand, I'm not going to sit here and guess what of the practically infinite number of possible wrong things that might have been without seeing the code.

Comment: The way I declared it in the initial code i wrote in the question is the same way I declared it. There are about 29274878734 lines of code, i only tried to copy the relevant section. There's nothing else that relates to the fields. @peter

Comment: I would need to see how you declared your form class, eg is it a `ModelForm` or a plain `Form`? If a model form, what's the `Meta` inner class? If a plain `Form`, what fields did you declare? etc. The references to not being sure about which "page" to put the code in make it sound like you're a little unsure on the difference between forms and models. But it doesn't seem like a productive area  for discussion following this question.

Comment: Yeah I may be a bit confused about the two. It's a 'ModelForm' though. I didn't define a Meta class maybe that was the problem. I defined the fields right under the main class.
I felt the Meta class was meant for ordering and specifying Verbose names.

Comment: Model forms need a `Meta` class with if nothing else a model assignment. They don't need explicit field definitions unless you want to override the default choices. The docs are pretty good here.

Comment: could you please take a look at this problem I have here. I'll appreciate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678446/csv-not-mapping-into-django-model