# csv not mapping into django model

Tags: python, django, csv, django-adaptors

I have a code that should run but isn't running. I have done massive amount of research and It's getting frustrating but it seems I just need a fresh pair of eyes.
I have used [csv importer](https://github.com/girasquid/django-csv-importer) and tweaked it a bit.
The code should upload csv, and read the columns into django fields! Viola! Not hard.
**In models.py I have:**

```
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from application.models import Analysis

class CSV(CsvModel):  
    csv_file     = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)  
    political_environment = DecimalField()
    GDP_per_capita = DecimalField()
    economic_diversification= DecimalField()
    inflation= DecimalField()
    monetary_credibility= DecimalField()
    access_to_finance= DecimalField()
#This is my major issues as An error keeps popping up saying 
#"Analysis model isn't defined" for dbModel despite defining it at the start
class Meta:
    dbModel = Analysis
    delimiter = ","

class Analysis
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['country']
        verbose_name = _('Analysis')

    political_environment = DecimalField()
    GDP_per_capita = DecimalField()
    economic_diversification= DecimalField()
    inflation= DecimalField()
    monetary_credibility= DecimalField()
    access_to_finance= DecimalField()
```

**In forms.py I have:**
    from credit.models import CSV

```
class CSVForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CSV

key_to_field_map = getattr(settings, 'CSVIMPORTER_KEY_TO_FIELD_MAP', lambda k: k.replace(' ','_').lower())
```

**Views**

```
from credit.models import CSV
from credit.forms import CSVForm,

def new(request):    
   if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = CSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)    
        if form.is_valid():    
            instance = form.save()    
            request.user.message_set.create(message='Uploaded CSV. Please associate fields below.')    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('associate-csv',args=[instance.id]))
    else:    
        form = CSVForm()    
    return render_to_response('new.html',     
        {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**html**

```
{% block content %}

<div id="content-main">
    <h2>Upload CSV</h2>
    <form action="." method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="accordion-body collapse{% if form.errors %} in{% endif %}" id="Data">
        <div class="accordion-inner row-fluid" label for="id_Data">
            <div class="span5">

                {% control form.political_environment %}
                {% control form.GDP_per_capita %}
                {% control form.economic_diversification %}
                {% control form.inflation %}
                {% control form.monetary_credibility %}
                {% control form.access_to_finance %}
</div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

**admin.py**

```
class AnalysisAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:        
        change_form_template = 'application/upload_csv.html'
        add_form_template = 'application/upload_csv.html'
```

What am I doing wrong or not doing right? This is meant to be simple but its getting frustration. Any help will do.
P.S: I'm new to django
Thanks!

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper pls I could use your help here

Comment: @yuvi please take a look at this question

Answer (score 0):

in your `models.py` first define `Analysis` and then define `CSV` like this:

```
from django.db import models
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from application.models import Analysis

class Analysis(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['country']
        verbose_name = _('Analysis')

    political_environment = DecimalField()
    GDP_per_capita = DecimalField()
    economic_diversification= DecimalField()
    inflation= DecimalField()
    monetary_credibility= DecimalField()
    access_to_finance= DecimalField()

class CSV(CsvModel):  
    csv_file     = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)  
    political_environment = DecimalField()
    GDP_per_capita = DecimalField()
    economic_diversification= DecimalField()
    inflation= DecimalField()
    monetary_credibility= DecimalField()
    access_to_finance= DecimalField()
#This is my major issues as An error keeps popping up saying 
#"Analysis model isn't defined" for dbModel despite defining it at the start
class Meta:
    dbModel = Analysis
    delimiter = ","
```