# Don't require field based on another field's value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django ModelForm where I want one field to be treated as conditionally required. I want it to be required by default, but not required depending on the value of another field. My model looks something along the lines of:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.BooleanField()
    bar = models.CharField(choices=(('A', 'A'),('B', 'B'),('C', 'C')),)
```

Neither have `null=True` or `blank=True` so both appear as "required" when I render my form, which is what I want.

However, I have some javascript on my form template that hides the `bar` field input depending on the value of the input for `foo`. In this case, when the form is submitted, I don't want to have any validation errors about `bar` being required.

I am trying to implement this logic in my ModelForm's `clean` method, like so:

```
def clean(self):
    data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
    if data.get('foo') == True and 'bar' in self.errors:
        del self.errors['bar']
    return data
```

However, this still seems to give me a "This field cannot be blank." error. I've noticed that my ModelForm also has an `_errors` dict, but if I try adding `del self._errors['bar']` I end up with an exception.

I have found some ways to do the opposite of what I want([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306800/django-form-validation-making-required-conditional), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967646/django-form-field-required-conditionally)), which is have the field not be required by default and then check it should be required in some cases in `clean`, but this is not what I want.

I've also tried adding `data['bar'] = "  "` as a workaround but then I get an error about not choosing one of the choices. Ideally, I'd rather just be able to save the empty string.

Comment: if data.get('foo') and 'bar' in self.errors:

Comment: Thanks, that is proper styling. However, it doesn't affect my issue here.

Comment: Are you editing or creating a new object?

Comment: I am creating a new object in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that in addition to the form's `clean` method being called, the [form also calls `post_clean` on the form's instance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f2c104ada605d9f7f7b7435778662c16d432dc32/django/forms/models.py#L428). Because the field on the model does not have `blank=True`, when the model is cleaned another error is raised and it gets passed back to the form.

To resolve, set `blank=True` on the model. This has the unwanted side effect of making the field appear as not required on the form. To make the field required on the form, simply set the required flag in init:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bar'].required = True
```

This, in addition to the `clean` method in the original question, is enough to create the conditionally required field that is required by default and not-required based on the value of another field.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `_clean_fields` method in order to provide your conditional changes:

```
def _clean_fields(self):
    if self.data.get('foo', None) == True:
        self.fields['bar'].required = False
    super(MyForm, self)._clean_fields()
```

Comment: Good to know this is a possible solution, but be warned, this is part of the internal Django API (noted by the leading `_`) and you may run into undocumented breaking changes.